Disable pm2 logs
I am running node app via pm2 this way:
pm2 start npm -- start --node-args="--max-old-space-size=1024"

and package.json includes:
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "...",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build && node dist/myManager",
    "build": "rimraf dist && tsc",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  . . .
}

It works as I need. Now I want to disable writing ~/.pm2/logs/npm-out.log.
How can I do it?
I try something like according to pm2 documentation - https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/log-management/
pm2 --output "/dev/null" start npm -- start --node-args="--max-old-space-size=1024"
pm2 --output="/dev/null" start npm -- start --node-args="--max-old-space-size=1024"
pm2 start npm -- start --node-args="--max-old-space-size=1024" --output "/dev/null"
pm2 start npm -- start --node-args="--max-old-space-size=1024" --output="/dev/null"

But it doesn't help.

Have you tried using command aliases instead:  pm2 start <process_id> -o "/dev/null" -e "/dev/null"

Just tried this one - pm2 start npm -- start --node-args="--max-old-space-size=1024" -o "/dev/null" -e "/dev/null". Not helped

You can run with flag --disable-logs to disable all logging from pm2.
pm2 --disable-logs start npm -- start --node-args="--max-old-space-size=1024"
It will still create the log files, but it won't write to them.

It works. Do you know maybe why the flags like '--output' or '--error' didn't work?

I do not. I do know that if you use a config file, setting out_file and error_file to /dev/null does work, because we use that in our production environment. So I'm guessing it's a bug or design flaw that it doesn't work with the flags. I tried to trace it through the source code, but I'm not familiar with the project source.
